# Conversion Error in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have been coding an assignment in C++ using Binary Search Trees, and while coding my "main" method, came across this error;

```
 91:37: error: conversion from ‘binaryTree*’ to non-scalar type ‘binaryTree’ requested
```

Line 91 is as follows;

```
 binaryTree bt = new binaryTree(root);
```

and I can't understand what's wrong with it, my lab tutor doesn't understand the error either.

- spelling is definitely correct

Any help would be great - thanks!

Comment: Your lab tutor really doesn't understand this error? Sounds like the blind leading the blind.

Comment: @sjdowling i just put it in meaning "i asked for help and they don't get it," sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by the operator new has type  `binaryTree *`. So it can be assigned to an object of this type:

```
binaryTree *bt = new binaryTree(root);
```

To call a methof for this pointer you have to use operator `->`. For example

```
bt->deleteTree();
```

Or you should dereference this pointer

```
( *bt ).deleteTree();
```

The other way is to use a reference to the allocated object. For example

```
binaryTree &bt = *new binaryTree(root);

//...

delete &bt;
```

Or

```
bt.deleteTree();
delete &bt;
```

Comment: thanks, but now i'm getting errors saying "request for member ‘deleteTree’ in ‘bt’, which is of non-class type ‘binaryTree*’" for example for all my methods

Comment: @MeganSime That's because `bt` is now a pointer to a value not a value so you have to dereference the pointer to use it either like `bt->deleteTree()` or `(*bt).deleteTree()`.

Comment: @Megan Sime See my updated post.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I would not recommend the making a reference from the allocated pointer like that. It's just confusing and isn't used in any code I have seen.

Comment: @sjdowling In any case you should know anout any possibility.

Comment: thank you so much this works :) (can't accept the answer yet)

Comment: The best solution to this is just `auto bt = std::make_unique<binaryTree>(root);`

Answer (score 0):

new returns a pointer and bt is not a pointer.

```
 binaryTree *bt = new binaryTree(root);
```

Comment: Rereading, I feel I may have made a mistake when recommending deletion. Too late, can't undo that now.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a pointer(binaryTree*) to a regular variable of type binaryTree. This cannot work.

You should instead do:

binaryTree* bt = new binaryTree(root);